# Python: Change values in a dict based on list?

Tags: python

I have a dict `check_dict` with keys and values. And another list `input_list` with `keys`.

I'm trying to make keys in `check_dict` to true whose keys are present in `input_list`.

```
input_list = ['name', 'phone']

check_dict = {'name':False,'phone':False,'address':False}
```

Expected output:

```
final_dict = {'name':True,'phone':True,'address':False}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use dict-comprehension:

```
>>> input_list = ['name', 'phone']
>>> check_dict = {'name':False,'phone':False,'address':False}
>>> final_dict = {k: True if k in input_list else False for k in check_dict}
>>> final_dict
{'name': True, 'phone': True, 'address': False}
```

---

As @ScootCork mentioned in a comment, this will do the same, but is much more readable:

```
final_dict = {k: k in input_list for k in check_dict}
```

Comment: You can just do `k in input_list` as it will already return the boolean value you need

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over `input_list` and then make an `if` statement. If a `string` from the `input_list` is in the `check_dict` then we change it's value to `True`

```
input_list = ['name', 'phone']
check_dict = {'name':False,'phone':False,'address':False}

for i in input_list:
    if i in check_dict:
        check_dict[i] = True
print(check_dict)
```